# assigning an R object to run a chain of command

Tags: r, command, shortcut

I am learning to use `bookdown` to render a PDF and Word document simultaneously from the same Rmd file. Since I want to view the PDF output using `Sumatra PDF reader`, which cannot auto reload modified documents for documents shown in the ebook UI (refer to `ReloadModified Documents` in https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/settings.html). I have created a single line to run everytime when I render the PDF file and view it in Sumatra PDF reader like below:

```
bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd',output_format = 'all',new_session = TRUE,preview=TRUE);
system('cmd.exe',input='taskkill /IM SumatraPDFPortable.exe');
system('cmd.exe',input='"C:/PortableApps/SumatraPDFPortable/SumatraPDFPortable.exe" "E:/output.pdf"')
```

I would like to know if it is possible to assign a R object (say: rendernow) to this line so that every time when I type "rendernow" and enter in R console, the above line will be executed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it a function:

```
rendernow <- function() {
  bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd',output_format = 'all',new_session = TRUE,preview=TRUE);
  system('cmd.exe',input='taskkill /IM SumatraPDFPortable.exe');
  system('cmd.exe',input='"C:/PortableApps/SumatraPDFPortable/SumatraPDFPortable.exe" "E:/output.pdf"')
}
```

Then you can invoke it via `rendernow()` (so you need the parenthesis)

---

Just for the fun of it, here's a solution where you do not need the parenthesis:

```
rendernow <- structure("", class = "rendernow")
print.rendernow <- function(x, ...) {
  bookdown::render_book('index.Rmd',output_format = 'all',new_session = TRUE,preview=TRUE);
  system('cmd.exe',input='taskkill /IM SumatraPDFPortable.exe');
  system('cmd.exe',input='"C:/PortableApps/SumatraPDFPortable/SumatraPDFPortable.exe" "E:/output.pdf"')
}
```

Then you just type `rendernow` and your steps are invoked.

Comment: I tried, the function only return literally the function itself

Comment: @lokheart: are you calling the function, like `rendernow()`?